# cannot display decision tree in python

Tags: python, graphviz, decision-tree

I cannot display the decision tree after this part of the code. It runs well, I don't receive any error but somehow I cannot see the output. Any help appreciated!

```
#Displaying the decision tree
from sklearn import tree
#from StringIO import StringIO
from io import StringIO
#from StringIO import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image

out=StringIO()

tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=out)
```

edit: I've added this part and then I receive the following error as No Module named 'pydotplus' . I am using Anaconda3 by the way . this is the code I've added later :

```
import pydotplus
graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(out.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: try this at a guess `import matplotlit.pyplot as plt; plt.show()`

Comment: still cannot display it

Comment: I've added these lines

Comment: This will not really help with displaying in python- but if you just want to see the tree, you could also copy the content of the out file you created into webgraphviz: http://www.webgraphviz.com/ and click the "generate graph" button. This will display the tree.

Comment: what can I do to display it within Jupyter?